# How do I set up Paypal Checkout buttons using Coldfusion?

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, payment

I am following the instructions here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#5-capture-the-transaction

And when I get to step 6.2 to verify the transaction on the server side I am not sure what to do. Do I need to install something on the server if I am using the javascript code shown?

Cheers!

Comment: Short answer is you don't need to do anything. The long answer is in most systems you want to log on your db server that a transaction happened. That way you show you customers something and so that you will have at least some of the transaction info at your disposal. Information like what did the customer buy is quite useful

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal Smart Payment Buttons allow you to accept payments and can work without any server side verification, as noted by [James A Mohler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845869/james-a-mohler)

However, you'll want to verify payment details on your server and will need to use a an SDK to integrate with ColdFusion.

You have a number of options:

1. Use a third party library such as [CFPayment](https://github.com/ghidinelli/cfpayment).  No longer recommended as more recent methods are more reliable and better supported.
2. Use [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  In this approach your server periodically makes a call to PayPal to get the details for recent transactions.  Older technology and works fine but your systems are only as up-to-date as your last call to PayPal.
3. Use [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/).  Recommended as this is allows PayPal to pass the information to your systems in a timely manner.  It should be simpler to implement as well as you just need a template that processes data passed received in JSON format.

I'm not suggesting you use the PayPal Checkout SDK as it's not available for ColdFusion.  There might be a third party library that would work, but I'm not aware of this.